# Dell Inspiron Admin bios password

Tags: bios, dell-inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron 14 5000 5491-10210U8G25ITOS
and I cant change nothing in bios, because it requires "admin" password.

I contact Dell support, but they didn't help..

- I really don't understand it- I bought that laptop and I own it, so that doesn't make me the admin?

Comment: Was the machine purchased used? It's possible that the previous owner had a password set, or that a family member or friend accidentally/purposefully set the admin password. They do not come with a BIOS password from the factory.

Comment: it's not used- I bought it from the shop. I am the only one that is using the computer. when I type this problem in Google, I find many complaints about it..